# Excel VBA: Inner Join on Collection Objects

Tags: excel, join, set, vba

I am trying to implement an Inner Join on Collections in Excel, but I am not seeing this produce accurate lists of objects.  Instead of one entry per match, I am seeing all of the entries from the first list in the result:

```
    'Public Functions
Public Function innerJoin(ByVal col1 As Collection, ByVal col2 As Collection) As Collection

Dim i As Integer
Dim searchValue As Integer
Dim totRemoved As Integer
totRemoved = 0

Dim tempCol As Collection
Set tempCol = New Collection
Dim tempCol2 As Collection
Set tempCol2 = New Collection

    For i = 1 To col2.Count
        tempCol2.Add col2.Item(i)
    Next i

For i = 1 To col1.Count

    searchValue = searchCollection(tempCol2, col1.Item(i))
    If searchValue = 0 Then
        tempCol2.Remove i - totRemoved
    totRemoved = totRemoved + 1
    Else
        tempCol.Add col1.Item(i)
    End If

Set innerJoin = tempCol

Next i
```

The code for searchCollection has been thoroughly unit-tested.

Comment: By inner-join do you mean intersection?

Comment: There is missing info in your question: where is the code for **searchCollection**, and how reliable is it? A couple of issues with your code: 1. what do you do with duplicates? 2. you remove items from tempCol2 based on their index, assuming that item 3 in tempCol2 appears as item 3 in col1? (collections don't guarantee the order of their items). When you iterate through collection objects you should be using a "FOR - EACH" loop (indexes are for arrays)

Comment: I'm trying to emulate the inner join from SQL, which would also be an intersection. Duplicates are included if present in both sets, excluded otherwise. I've taken steps to guarantee the orders of the collection, and searchCollection uses a bi-directional search tree algorithm to search a collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless there is something I am missing about your requirements, your code seems much more complex than it needs be. In particular -- why add things to a collection only to later remove them? A dictionary, accessible if you include a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` (under `Tools/References` in the VBA editor), seems like a natural choice. Does the following work for you?

```
Function Intersect(col1 As Collection, col2 As Collection) As Collection
    Dim intCol As New Collection
    Dim colDict As New Dictionary
    Dim v As Variant

    'Create dictionary of objects in col2
    For Each v In col2
        colDict.Add v, 0
    Next v

    'loop through col1, adding items in colDict to intCol
    For Each v In col1
        If colDict.Exists(v) Then intCol.Add v
    Next v
    Set Intersect = intCol
End Function
```

Here is a test:

```
Sub test()
    Dim Moods As New Collection
    Dim Colors As New Collection
    Dim ColorMoods As Collection
    Dim v As Variant

    Moods.Add "Sad"
    Moods.Add "Happy"
    Moods.Add "Blue"
    Moods.Add "Black"
    Moods.Add "Content"

    Colors.Add "Yellow"
    Colors.Add "Green"
    Colors.Add "Red"
    Colors.Add "Blue"
    Colors.Add "White"
    Colors.Add "Black"

    Set ColorMoods = Intersect(Moods, Colors)
    For Each v In ColorMoods
        Debug.Print v
    Next v
End Sub
```

Output:

```
Blue
Black
```

Comment: Beautiful!  I also implemented Subtract() with the same methodology and both work perfectly!  Thank you!